# Calculating embedding overload problems with BERT

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, bert-language-model, embedding

I'm trying to calculate the embedding of a sentence using BERT. After I input the sentence into BERT, I calculate the Mean-pooling, which is used as the embedding of the sentence.

### Problem

My code can calculate the embedding of sentences, but the computational cost is very high. I don't know what's wrong and I hope someone can help me.

#### Install BERT

```
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModel
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
```

#### Get Embedding Function

```
# get the word embedding from BERT
def get_word_embedding(text:str):
    input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode(text)).unsqueeze(0)  # Batch size 1
    outputs = model(input_ids)
    last_hidden_states = outputs[1]  
    # The last hidden-state is the first element of the output tuple
    return last_hidden_states[0]
```

#### Data

The maximum number of words in the text is 50. I calculate the entity+text embedding

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvw4Y.png)

#### Run code

`entity_desc` is my data.
It's this step that overloads my computer every time I run it.
Please help me!!!

I was use RAM 80GB machine in Colab.

```
entity_embedding = {}
for i in range(len(entity_desc)):
    entity = entity_desc['entity'][i]
    text = entity_desc['text'][i]
    entity += ' ' + text
    entity_embedding[entity_desc['entity_id'][i]] = get_word_embedding(entity)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem.
The reason for the memory overload was that I wasn't saving the tensor to the GPU, so I made the following changes to the code.

```
model = model.to(device)


import torch
# get the word embedding from BERT
def get_word_embedding(text:str):
    input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode(text)).unsqueeze(0)  # Batch size 1
    input_ids = input_ids.to(device)

    outputs = model(input_ids)
    last_hidden_states = outputs[1]
    last_hidden_states = last_hidden_states.to(device)  
    # The last hidden-state is the first element of the output tuple
    return last_hidden_states[0].detach().to(device)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be storing sentence embedding in the GPU. Try to move it to cpu before returning it.

```py
# get the word embedding from BERT
def get_word_embedding(text:str):
    input_ids = torch.tensor(tokenizer.encode(text)).unsqueeze(0)  # Batch size 1
    outputs = model(input_ids)
    last_hidden_states = outputs[1]  
    # The last hidden-state is the first element of the output tuple
    return last_hidden_states[0].detach().cpu()
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It seems like I store the embedding in the CPU. I will try to store the embeddings in GPU.